# Create previous back button for image gallery. Images loaded from folder as array

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have images loaded from folder via PHP. Next button works with settimeout, when button is clicked jQuery hide image and show next image. How could i make previous button ? 
Here is gallery link. 
http://onlinegallery.online/index.php
Buttons are hidden at the right top after click > button at the bottom right on main page.

I tried to add this code below for previous button
but it shows some another image-div , not previous.

```
jQuery(".hidewinprev").on("click keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.type == "click" || e.keyCode == 39) {
       jQuery('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(500)
    .prev()
    .fadeIn(500)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
    jQuery('#slideshow > div').css('display','none');
     jQuery('#slideshow > div:first').css('display','flex'); 

    }
});


//php scandir echo images

$list = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($list as $file) {
      if (is_file($dir . '/' . $file)) {
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if ($ext == 'gif' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'png') {
          echo "<div class='' data-title='" . basename($file,".$ext") . "'>\n<img src=\"" . $dir . '/' . $file . "\" alt=\"" . $dir . "\"><br />\n</div>\n";

        }
      }
    }

//html output

<div><img></div>
<div><img></div>
....


//button next jquery works

jQuery(".hidewinnext").on("click keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.type == "click" || e.keyCode == 39) {
       jQuery('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(500)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(500)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
    jQuery('#slideshow > div').css('display','none');
     jQuery('#slideshow > div:first').css('display','flex'); 

    }
});


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMnln.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code:

HTML Code:

```
<div id="big-image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/1/">
</div>
<div class="small-images">
    <img class="selected" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/sports/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/fashion/1/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/city/1/">
</div>
        <button id="prev">Prev</button>
        <button id="next">Next</button>
```

JS Code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-images img").click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            index = $this.index();
        $(".small-images img").removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
    $('#next').click(function(){ 
        var $selected = $('.selected');
        var index = $selected.next('img').index();
        if(index == -1){
            index = 0;
        }
        var $curr = $(".small-images img").eq(index);
        $(".small-images img").removeClass('selected');
        $curr.addClass('selected');
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });

    $('#prev').click(function(){ 
        var $selected = $('.selected');
        var index = $selected.prev('img').index();
        var $curr = $(".small-images img").eq(index);
        $(".small-images img").removeClass('selected');
        $curr.addClass('selected');
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

CSS Code:

```
.small-images a, .big-images a {
    display:inline-block
}
.small-images .selected {
    border:1px solid red
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vb5pk408/

Comment: Oh. It's really hard to implement this code to my created code. I thought it would be some way to use .prev jquery easy for show preview image. gallery is not entirely created to be a slider but rather a slideshow gallery but if there was such a possibility I would like to give users such an option...preview button.

Comment: I can't put a selected class to image. I'm using php for loading images from folder. So when I give a class to script which is loading images <img class='selected' src=\"" . $dir . '/' . $file . "\" alt=\"" . $dir . "\"> all loaded images has class selected.